# VSCode keeps using wrong node version

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am running node.js version 18 using nvm on my Mac. node -v in the OSX terminal as well as in the VSCode terminal prints out the correct version (both zsh).

However, if I run node -v as a npm script through the VSCode menu (Terminal > Run Task > "node-version") it prints out an older version of node (v16 in this case).

I can't find any setting for this. Does anybody know where I can configure the currently wrong node version?

Thanks, Gerry

Comment: I will recommend using `n` its much simpler and easier to use

Comment: Please add to your question post the output of `whereis node`, of `which node`, and of `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it running. There were some old node bins under /usr/local/bin which were picked up by VSCode. After running

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
```

and restart VSCode the node version is correct.